# Does GridGain support distributed lock?

Tags: gridgain

Does GridGain support distributed lock?

In my scenario, I want to add distributed lock in my code and make sure only one node executes the code at the same time. Here is the sample code:

```
final Grid grid = GridGain.start("config/default-config.xml");

GridCache<Object, Object> cache = grid.cache("partitioned_tx"); 

ExecutorService exec = grid.compute().executorService();

//Lock here

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
   final int index = i;

   exec.submit(new GridRunnable() {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = -8705359518901621360L;

     @Override
     public void run() {
       System.out.println("The task-"+index+" is executed on "+grid.forLocal().node().toString());
     }
   });
}

//unlock here
exec.shutdown();
exec.awaitTermination(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GridGain supports distributed locks, as well as distributed transactions. Please take a look at [Basic Distributed Locks](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Getting+Started#GettingStarted-BasicDistributedLocks) documentation in [Getting Started](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Getting+Started) guide.